# How to test RxJS switchMap with Jasmine in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, angular-test, switchmap

In my Angular project I have this code in one of my components:

```js
  delete(post: PostInterface): void {
    const delete$ = this.appDataService.proxy
      .delete(post, this.paginate)
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this.loadDatas()));

    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.appDataService.start(delete$, 'delete').subscribe()
    );
  }
```

And in my spec file:

```js
describe('PostListComponent', () => {
  let component: PostListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PostListComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // ...
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostListComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });

  describe('functions', () => {
    it('should be delete with proxy.delete() and reload datas', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'loadDatas');

      component.delete(1);

      flush();

      expect(component.loadDatas).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }));
  });
});
```

In real environment the `switchMap` works fine, but in test it fails with this message:

```
PostListComponent > functions > should be delete with proxy.delete() and reload datas

Expected spy loadDatas to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
```

Why isn't run the `switchMap` in my test? Any idea?

Comment: Won't this answer solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910827/angular-unit-test-switchmap-not-working

Comment: @S.Hashiba no, I tried it before ask question

Answer (score 0):

The reason the test is not working as expected lays probably in the fact that you do not `subscribe` the Observable.

It is the subscription that starts the stream, i.e. that fires the execution of whatever code is embedded in the Observable chain.

So, you may want to try this version of the test to see if the situation improves

```
 describe('functions', () => {
    it('should be delete with proxy.delete() and reload datas', (done) => {
      spyOn(component, 'loadDatas');

      component.delete(1).subscribe({
        next: err => done(err),
        complete: () => {
           expect(component.loadDatas).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
           done();
        }
      });

      flush();

    });
  });
```

As you see I am not using `fakeAsync` and I assume that `delete` is actually exectued.

Comment: The `component.delete()` os a void. Not an observable. And in this function the subscribe is there.

Comment: After reading again the question I see that `delete` returns a void. At the same time I am wondering whether `this.appDataService.start(delete$, 'delete').subscribe()` actually fires some async logic. If this code is executed asynchrnously, then the `expect` logic may be executed before the async logic completes and therefore before `loadDatas` gets executed.

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve the issue? Need to refsctor the component code to make it testable or is there any other way to test it in this form?

Comment: I would move the code to an external service, passed to the Component via Dependency Injection, so that the Component needs only to subscribe either in some method or using the `async` pipe. The service, on the other hand, is a simpler Typscript class which you could test with the technique shown in my response

Comment: It sounds as a refactor on the code, and not a solution for the switchMap issue.

Comment: Indeed it is, it is a refactoring. I still think it is the best way to proceed. Generally speaking, in my opinion at least, the less code is in the components and the more logic is moved to services the better it is. I am aware this is not science, so any different opinion may be as valid as mine.

Comment: I understand what you say, but if I move the code to a different file (a service) the problem still will be with us, just in another place.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still say `Expected spy loadDatas to have been called once. It was called 0 times.`

Comment: Can you reproduce this case on a stackblitz?

Comment: Sure, here is it: https://angular-3fs5jm.stackblitz.io

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see the test